# Event manager in vlc library with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

I wrote a code that implement vlc player and I want to listen to state change (playing, pause, stop, opening ...) and media duration changing. But I found out that some event works where other doesn't.

```
instance = vlc.Instance()
media = instance.media_new(src)
self.player = instance.media_player_new()
self.event_manager = self.player.event_manager()

self.event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaStateChanged, self.call_state)
self.event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerMediaChanged, self.display)


def display(self, event):
    self.show()
 def call_state(self, event):
        print(self.player.get_state())
```

Here MediaPlayerMediaChanged works fine and MediaStateChanged doesn't.

Comment: whitch function work and witch doesen't ?

Comment: self.event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerMediaChanged, self.display) this one works

Comment: @msakni22 from the name, it seems like that event is when the *media* state is changed. I'm not sure about what that refers to, but if that's the case, you should probably use the `media.event_manager()` and attach that event type to it. Otherwise, you probably want to attach specific *player* event changes to the player's `event_manager`, like `MediaPlayerPaused`, `MediaPlayerStopped` or `MediaPlayerPlaying`.

Comment: yeah, that's the solution that I decided to apply right now, I attached each state change to the same function. Just there's a state called "MediaPlayerOpening" I want to put the media player on that state, is it possible ?